# How do I periodically change my wallpaper to random motivational text?

Tags: windows, desktop, desktop-customization

Is there a Windows software that randomly changes the wallpaper and puts a random text on top of it? I should be able to enter this text (just a list of quotes).

The purpose is to constantly remind me of some short-term goals (like right now, I have a one-month goal that requires me to constantly remember every day).

Basically [something like this](https://superuser.com/questions/97737/software-for-random-wallpaper-but-with-custom-text) but for Windows (bonus points if it also works on MacOSX).

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: But you're working so hard... you'll never actually *see* your desktop!

Answer (score 3):

Get a desktop wallpaper changer [(such as **cross-platform Wally**)](http://lifehacker.com/#!5404316/keep-your-wallpaper-fresh-with-cross+platform-wally), and use this collection of motivational wallpapers recently featured by [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com):

> [Minimal Wall Is A Collection of Simple (and Often Motivational) Wallpapers](http://lifehacker.com/#!5790103/minimal-wall-is-a-collection-of-simple-and-often-motivational-wallpapers)

If you're using Windows 7, you can use the built-in desktop wallpaper changer, and just download the collection of wallpapers to your computer and create a theme.  Short and sweet.

Answer (score 1):

if you're running windows xp there's a [powertoy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ce1d596b-6851-4948-ab76-b5ff22d37d69&displaylang=en) for that. Its [native to 7](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-7/automatically-rotate-wallpapers-in-windows-7/). totally no idea about vista. Presumably you'd have to hack together some way to have the motivational text in the wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

Heave you heard of Active Desktop?

Create an HTML (with JavaScript) page that shows your quotes randomly. Set this HTML file as Active Desktop wallpaper.

Comment: It's now deprecated and only works till Windows XP. It has been replaced by gadgets...

Answer (score 0):

You could also use things like [Google Calendar notifications](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28573/how-to-enable-desktop-notifications-for-google-calendar-in-chrome/) to remind you of things on various devices, whether you are on the desktop or a smart phone. It can do things like pop-ups and SMS.